# Assign a unique ID to the points based on row-wise difference in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to assign unique IDs say 1,2, 3, …,n for the points in R dataframe `dt`. Starting from the first row a point is assigned ID 1 if the row-wise difference of `x` or `y` or both is `<10`.  The point continuously gets ID 1 until there is a gap in `Date` and the difference in `x` or `y` or both is `<10`. So A single ID is assigned for a point for all the days until either (i) there is a gap in `Date` and/or (ii) the row-wise difference of `x` or `y` or both is `<10`.
I expect output like in `expectedid` column in the `dt` or like in this plot.
[image]

Or the other way to achieve what I want is to subset all the points from `dt` that has `<10` difference in row-wise `x` or `y` or both and no gaps in the date, assign/write them as a set of dataframe and continue for next set and so on.

```
dt<-structure(list(x = c(-175, -173, -175, -171, -177, -169, -177, 
-166, -178, -163, -176, -161, -176, -178, -179, -179, -121, -121
), y = c(38, 38, 71, 38, 75, 38, 77, 39, 80, 38, 80, 38, 80, 
80, 80, 80, 39, 40), Date = structure(c(17321, 17322, 17323, 
17323, 17324, 17324, 17325, 17325, 17326, 17326, 17327, 17327, 
17328, 17329, 17330, 17330, 17333, 17334), class = "Date"), id = c(1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), expectedid = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), y = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), expectedid = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

plt<-ggplot(dt,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point(size=6,color="Blue")+
  facet_wrap(~Date)+
  geom_text(aes(label=expectedid),color="White")
plt
```

After implementing the solution suggested, it worked as expected for almost all cases. However in some cases of real data it did not when the date is changed. For example, in the sample data and code below it works as expected if the last date is `1979-09-06` and does not work when the last date is `1979-09-07`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)

id<-"1gL_76PyX9FDTP0JpQfTinlk0C9jbo2KJ"
sampledt<-read_csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))
sampledt

sampledt <- sampledt %>% 
 mutate(row = row_number())

#Work as expected and indicates ID 1 and 2 when the last date is 1979-09-06
#However it does ntow ork as expected and give two events ID1 and id2 when I change the date to 1979-09-07 as in original data

#Workign as expected 
# sampledt_working<-sampledt%>%
#           filter(Date < "1979-09-07")
# 
# sampledt<-sampledt_working

#The code is not working if date is changed. It does not  assign ID 2 as expected
sampledt<-sampledt

sampledt %>% 
 left_join(sampledt %>% mutate(Date = Date - 1), by = "Date") %>%
 filter(abs(x.y - x.x) <= 1 & abs(y.y - y.x) <= 1) -> working_matches
working_matches

sampledt1<-working_matches %>% 
 select(row.x, row.y) %>%
 as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE) %>% 
 mutate(group = group_components()) %>%
 activate(nodes) %>%
 data.frame() %>%
 mutate(row = as.integer(name)) %>%
 right_join(sampledt, by = c("row")) %>% 
 mutate(group = group %>% as.factor %>% forcats::fct_inorder() %>% as.integer())
sampledt1

pntdt<-sampledt1%>%
 group_by(Date,group)%>%
 slice(which.max(val)) 
pntdt

plt<-ggplot(sampledt1,aes(x=x,y=y))+
 geom_tile(aes(fill=val))+
 facet_wrap(~Date)+
 geom_point(data=pntdt,color="Red",size=5)+
 geom_text(data=pntdt,aes(label=group),color="White")
plt
```

Comment: For scoping potential approaches to be good enough for your use case, it would help to know approx how many unique ID's you have per day. A brute force approach that works for ten IDs might be impossibly slow if you have 100k.

Comment: thanks, @Jon, I have a maximum of 4 points in a single day, the `y` range from 35 to 80 and x from -180 to -90 ( always).

Comment: btw row 3 to row 5 has a y change of 4, but listed as same id. Is the tolerance >3 or should that be new id?

Comment: just rechecked, the difference can be up to <10 and still be in the same group, modified the question.

Comment: Struggling to understand how this works in general. What if there are two points on the same day which are close enough to have the same ID, but then each day they get further apart until they are further than 10 from each other. However on each subsequent day they didn't get more than 10 from a previous point with that ID... Do they still have the same ID?

Comment: @pseudospin, in actual data there can't be two points in the same day close enough to have the same ID. I guess I have to play around the threshold of 10 to make sure there is not any single ID for two points in a day. In general one ID starts and moves by date until there is date gap but close enough to be within difference in 10 in location; no same ID for two points in a single day.

Comment: In your sample data there is a day with two points with identical x and y and you gave them the same ID.

Comment: in the `Date==2017-06-06` there are two points, with ids `1` and `2`. `1` continue from previous day because the location difference is `10`.  id `2` start here because a new point emerges that  does not satisfy the overlapping conditions with the previous day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to me like a network problem, since we are trying to identify links between observations on subsequent days which are sufficiently close, and to use those links to establish "membership" with a given ID.

Edited to reflect suggestion from @pseudospin to use `group_components()` instead of `group_fast_greedy()`. It now correctly attributes each entity to a consistent group. The raw output of that algorithm doesn't label the groups in the same order, but we can fix that downstream, as shown below.

[image]

First, let's add a row number to the original data to help for tracking

```
dt <- dt %>% mutate(row = row_number())
```

Now, I want to connect each observation to all its potential matches by connecting with "next day" version of table. The "next day" version has it's day shifted back one to connect with "today." This could also be done with a "non-equi join" with data.table or fuzzyjoin, but is small enough to work as a left_join then filter

```
dt %>% 
  left_join(dt %>% mutate(Date = Date - 1), by = "Date") %>%
  # Of all the "next day matches," only keep the nearby ones
  filter(abs(x.y - x.x) <= 10 & abs(y.y - y.x) <= 10) -> working_matches
```

Now I pull in tidygraph, a wrapper around igraph, to create clusters from the edges. "Edges" here being connections between observations. The `tidygraph::group_components()` function does the heavy lifting here, and puts all the observations that connect to each other into separate groups.

```
library(tidygraph)
working_matches %>% 
  select(row.x, row.y) %>%
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(group = group_components()) %>%

  # extract group info which has been assigned to the nodes (aka
  #  the observations)
  activate(nodes) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(row = as.integer(name)) %>%
  
  # apply to original data
  right_join(dt, by = c("row")) %>% 

  # One method for numbering groups in order of first appearance
  mutate(group = group %>% as.factor %>% forcats::fct_inorder() %>% as.integer())
  
  # plot
  ggplot(aes(x, y, label = group)) +
  geom_text() +
  facet_wrap(~Date)
```

Comment: I've just done this the same way (but with igraph and data.table) and it worked fine. I can't see where your bug is, if you look at the graph there are 3 clusters, but when you extract the nodes as a data.frame there are 5 groups. Is group in that table something else, not clusters?

Comment: found it.  Change `group_fast_greedy()` to `group_components()` and it produces the graph in the question.

Comment: I've added some more annotation, hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @Jon the solution worked well for most cases but it did not on occasions. I have added the working and not working scenarios in the modified question, can you please have a look and hint why it may be behaving as expected in that specific case. I guess it may be how `group_components()` behave but not sure. Thank you